# Why do string theory and Hopf algebra renormalization seem to have no intersection?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, renormalization, hopf-algebra

[Hopf algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra) appears in recent papers that systematize renormalization of quantum field theory (QFT). For example see [Connes' work and citing papers](http://www.google.com/search?q=connes+hopf+site%3Aarxiv.org&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) or a paper referenced [here on PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/formalizing-quantum-field-theory):

R. E. Borcherds, "Renormalization and quantum field theory"
http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0129

This seems to be an effort that is separate from string theory, but I wonder if they are compatible. Since "compatible" is perhaps too loose of a term, I'm asking:

> Why do string theory and Hopf algebra renormalization seem to have no intersection?

If the reader feels the question could be improved by rewriting, please so assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to renormalize a theory that gives UV finite answers?

Comment: Why do you want to see a reference saying that finite theories don't need a renormalization treatment?

Answer (score -1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2203 sure bout that?

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: To expand of David's comment, link only answers are discouraged across the entire Stack Exchange network, because Stack Exchange aims to be a content host, not a redirection cache. At a minimum you need to summarize what the linked paper is about and how it connects to the question as asked.