# QFT as a rigorous mathematical theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

I understood that quantum field theory is essentially based on a problematic mathematical basis. Can someone please explain what is the fundamental problem to formulate QFT as a rigorous mathematical theory? It's clear that it has to do with renormalization but similar techniques are already exist in analytically number theory (and are considered to be a mathematical theory).

Comment: Be aware that there are multiple QFT's, some of which aren't so problematic; see [Which QFTs were rigorously constructed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27569).

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27665/2451 and links therein.