# Epstein-Glaser causal perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, path-integral

Why does [causal perturbation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_perturbation_theory) in the sense of Epstein Glaser fall under algebraic QFT rather than heuristic QFT in renormalization?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6530/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I'm not fully certain what your question here is. What do you mean with "fall into the favor of"?

Comment: Belong to the category of I should say

Answer (score 3):

Because its statements and methods are fully rigorous, hence constitute mathematical physics. No unproved or unprovable claims are made. See https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/causal-perturbation-theory/
for an exposition of the principles and results.

There is other work on renormalization in relativistic QFT that is fully rigorous and hence qualifies as algebraic QFT, for example Salmhofer's work, which treats renormalization in a rigorous formal power series framework. See Salmhofer's book ''Renormalization: an introduction'', Springer 2013.