# Mathematics of Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

Edward Witten has stated that QFT is not mathematically rigorous, and that string theory helps us in unifying the forces much better. Can you give me a suitable example in which QFT lacks mathematical rigour?

Comment: Have you checked this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6530/

Comment: Yeah that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Girdar Your welcome!