# Rigorous mathematical formalism of particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, mathematical-physics, standard-model, elementary-particles

Can anyone provide me with a rigorous mathematical definition of the [fundamental particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) (all fundamental bosons and fermions), reflecting the analogy of action of groups with interaction of particles, isospin and mediating forces? An answer would be preferable, but a link of an appropriate source would also suffice.

Comment: Would this help you better define what you're looking for? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27665/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Danu I understand the 6/7 Wightman axioms but fail to capture how does the concepts of fundamnetal particles, quarks-leptons, or bosons mediating forces etc. come from those.

Comment: Actually, the book *The Structure and Interpretation of the Standard Model* addresses this very question!

Comment: Perhaps this paper could be a starting point, I didn't read it by now but it seems to deal with a very related question and tries to restrict itself to first quantization to avoid some mathematical pittfalls...: http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1626/

Comment: I just realized that it's by the same author as the book suggested by @AlexNelson ...

Comment: Here is a paper by Buchholz, which discusses the particle concept in algebraic quantum field theory to some extend: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9511023

Answer (score 2):

The [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics is a theoretical framework that encapsulates almost all elementary particle data to date. The full Lagrangian [takes pages.](http://einstein-schrodinger.com/Standard_Model.pdf)

In your comment:

> @Danu I understand the 6/7 Wightman axioms but fail to capture how does the concepts of fundamnetal particles, quarks-leptons, or bosons mediating forces etc. come from those.

Physics theoretical  models are not just mathematical models, where one starts from axioms and ends up with predictions of the theory. The models are chosen to describe known data, their predictions are checked continuously agains new data . Isospin, particle exchanges etc are all in the lagrangian and quantum field theory tools are used to calculate crossections etc to be checked by future data. Th SM developed over the years after observing the symmetries that existed in the experimental data , for example the [eightfold way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29) which led to the proposal of the quarks . The symmetries disclosed by **the data**  led to the SM Lagrangian which was **chosen** to display these symmetries of SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) .