# Using intuition to understand physics concepts, how and when to let that need for intuition go?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, education

Those of us who grew up solving Newtonian mechanics, electrostatics, and calculus of 1-3 variables problems developed good intuition for understanding simple concepts. This helped me condition a problem, select a good coordinate system or frame of reference, and often provided a concrete example to more complex theories. For instance, it's impossible to picture a 100-dimensional gradient, but knowing a slope and a surface plane on a 3-D manifold makes it easy to imagine.

I'm getting to a point where the intuition is coming at a higher and higher cost as problems become more difficult. Differential forms are a good example, where the geometric interpretations are expensive to imagine and only really help in low dimensional space. I get the sense that quantum mechanics (or any "analogy" to it) becomes almost impossible to imagine.

For practitioners of physics: do you have to stop relying on geometric intuition, and just trust the mechanics/math? Or do you develop more mathematical intuition so visual analogies aren't necessary?

Comment: Related (and also closed): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27665/50583 This is primarily opinion-based because even expert physicists vary wildly in how much they rely on intuition vs. mathematical rigor.

Comment: I personally depend on visual analogies most of the time even after many years. But I mostly deal with pretty concrete, real things.  A 100-dimensional gradient wouldn't be too bad, but a four-dimensional knot is beyond me.  Some mathematicians have claimed to have trained themselves to visualize higher-dimensional forms, but I suspect that they really were visualizing analogies and knew the math well enough to know when the analogies were misleading.

Comment: Depends on the person. I barely use any visual intuition at all -- my personal notes have less than one picture per 100 pages. But I have friends that, when asked to describe something about a high-dimensional fiber bundle, will start drawing pictures in the air with their hands as if they're seeing something. What _is_ essential is that you have _some_ intuition for the equations, but that could be, e.g. just formal intuition about their formal properties.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for the link! That's an interesting conversation but only a few points seem relevant. Already some helpful comments have been posted here, however I'm happy to re-post on a different StackExchange site. Can you point me to the correct one?