# What aspects of QFT do mathematicians find troublesome?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

What aspects of "conventional" quantum field theory (i.e. what's used by most practicing physicists) are considered to be lacking mathematical rigor?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4068/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You might get better answers if you ask mathematicians...

Comment: The Wick rotation comes to mind ...